# Unable to access a public state in angular project?

Tags: angularjs

in my web app am using angular-ui-router for state change. Below is my route.config file.

**route-config.js**

```
$stateProvider
  .state('login', {
      url: '/',
      views:{
          pageContent:{
              templateUrl: 'Login/login_default.html',
              controller: 'loginController'
          },
          footer:{
              templateUrl: 'common/footer.html',
              controller: 'footerController'                 
          }
      },onEnter: function(){
       // if(true){ $state.go('dashboard')}
      },resolve:{
        dependencies:['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load(['ui.bootstrap','ngMessages','headerCtrl','footerCtrl']);                
        }],
        loginController:['$q', '$ocLazyLoad','dependencies',function($q, $ocLazyLoad,dependencies) {
           var deferred = $q.defer();                   
           require.ensure(['./styles/login/login.less'], function (require) {
                          var mod = require('./Login');
                           $ocLazyLoad.load({
                            name: mod.name,
                          });                
            deferred.resolve(mod.controller);
          });
          return deferred.promise;
        }]

      },public:true
  })
  .state('Password', {
      url: '/Password?token',
      views:{
          header:{
            templateUrl: 'common/header.html',
            controller:"headerController"                 
          },
          pageContent:{
            templateUrl: 'ForgotPassword/forgotPassword.html',
            controller: 'forgotPasswordCtrl'
          },
          footer:{
            templateUrl: 'common/innerFooter.html',
              controller: 'footerController'                   
          }
      },
      resolve:{     
        dependencies:['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load(['headerCtrl','ui.bootstrap']);
        }],             
        forgotPasswordCtrl:['$q','$ocLazyLoad','dependencies', function($q,$ocLazyLoad,dependencies) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            require.ensure(['./styles/forgotPassword/forgotPassword.less'], function (require) {
              var mod = require('./ForgotPassword');
              $ocLazyLoad.load({                
                name: mod.name,
              });                                   
              deferred.resolve(mod.controller);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
          }] 
      },public:true
    });
```

In index.js file am checking the $stateChange as below.

```
run(function($http,$rootScope,$cookieStore,$location,$window,$state) {   
   $rootScope.token = $http.defaults.headers.common['SessionID'];  
   $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
      let loggedIn = $cookieStore.get('success');
      if(!toState.public && !loggedIn){
        $state.go('login');
        event.preventDefault(); 
      }
   });
});
```

And below is the Html page on which on click on password button it should go to forgot password page or if i will type password on the URL it should go to the password page.

```
<div class="inp-wrapper frgtpwd">
                  <a style="text-decoration:none;color:#000;" ui-sref="Password" class="password">FORGOT PASSWORD ?</a>
                 </div>
```

I tried everything but unable to fix this issue. If i will check the `toState.name` in $statechangeStart function and try to go to the password page then it is going under a continuous loop and throwing error like `Maximum call stack`(something like this).

Comment: Just place a `event.preventDefault();` before you check your `toState.name` part in your `$statechangeStart` function. Hope it will prevent the infinite loop.

Comment: I put ` event.preventDefault();` before ` $state.go('login');`, but it didn't work.

Comment: You mean to say, you are still getting that `Maximum call stack` error?

Comment: not maximum call stack error but if i will type in url "/Password" then it is not going to the specific page. Or if i will copy the url  `"localhost:8080/#/Password"` and put it in browser URL then it is redirecting me to the login page.